# JS Find the missing letter (alphabet - array)

Tags: javascript, arrays, alphabetical

> Write a function that takes an array of consecutive (increasing) letters as input and that returns the missing letter in the array.
> It will be always exactly one letter be missing. The array will always contain letters in only one case.
> Example:
>
> ```
> ["a","b","c","d","f"] -> "e"
> ["O","Q","R","S"] -> "P"
> ```

Why don't my functions work?

```
function findMissingLetter(array)
{
  let alphabetArr = Array.from('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
  let alphabetSlice = alphabetArr.slice(alphabetArr.indexOf(array[0]), alphabetArr.indexOf(array[array.length - 1]) + 1);

    let missingLetter = alphabetSlice.forEach((e, i) => {
         if (e !== array[i]) {
            return e;
        }
    });

return missingLetter;
}


function findMissingLetter(array)
{
  let alphabetArr = Array.from('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
  let alphabetSlice = alphabetArr.slice(alphabetArr.indexOf(array[0]), alphabetArr.indexOf(array[array.length - 1]) + 1);

    let missingLetter = alphabetSlice.map((e, i) => {
         if (e !== array[i]) {
            return e;
        }
    })[0];

return missingLetter;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work how? What results do you expect? What do you get instead? What debugging have you done?

Comment: Neither `forEach` nor `map` is the correct way to look for a single item in an array. Either use a `for`/`for-of` loop you can break out of (probably `for` since you want the index), or `find` (to find the item itself), or `findIndex` (to find its index). Your basic approach is fine. Look at `find` and read up on what the callback should return and you'll be good. :-)

Comment: `findMissingLetter(["a","b","c","d","f"])`  I get undefined.

Comment: But aren't for/for-of loops doing exactly the same as forEach method?

Comment: The *"...you can break out of..."* part of that sentence was important. :-) You can't break out of a `forEach` (except by throwing an error).

Answer (score 3):

For searching for one element in an array use `for` loop, like this:

```js
for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(array[i] !== alphabetSlice[i])
        return alphabetSlice[i];
}
```

In this approach you will search for first difference between two arrays. And the difference will be your missing letter :)

---

#### Why map doesn't work in this example?

`map` function takes data and replaces it with "re-arranged" data. This:

```js
alphabetSlice.map((e, i) => {
    if (e !== array[i]) {
        return e;
    }
}); // for your example will create array
```

will create `[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, 'e', 'f']`, so the first element is `undefined`.

##### Why the result array has `undefined`?

Because you have `return` statement in `if`. So when the expression in `if` is false, you won't return any value, so the value is `undefined`.

More about map you can read on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Answer (score 1):

Actually just replace `forEach` with `find` and change what you're returning, and it will do what's needed.

```js
function findMissingLetter(array)
{
    let alphabetArr = Array.from('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
    let alphabetSlice = alphabetArr.slice(alphabetArr.indexOf(array[0]), alphabetArr.indexOf(array[array.length - 1]) + 1);

    let missingLetter = alphabetSlice.find((e, i) => e !== array[i]);

    return missingLetter;
}

console.log(findMissingLetter(["a","b","c","d","f"]))
console.log(findMissingLetter(["O","Q","R","S"]))
```

[Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) executes a provided function once for each array element.

[Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) returns the value of the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function.

Answer (score 0):

1. Iterate over the array from `0` till `length - 1`
2. At each iteration, get the `UTF-16 code` of the current and next characters using [`String#charCodeAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt), which should have a difference of `1` if they are after each other (given that they're of the same case)
3. If the code of the `next` element doesn't equal to the current one + 1, compute the missing character using [`String#fromCharCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) on current code + 1

```js
const findMissingLetter = (array = []) => {
  for(let i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
    const current = array[i].charCodeAt(), next = array[i+1].charCodeAt();
    const expected = current+1;
    if(next !== expected) {
      return String.fromCharCode(expected);
    }
  }
}

console.log( findMissingLetter(["a","b","c","d","f"]) );
console.log( findMissingLetter(["O","Q","R","S"]) );
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to return from a `forEach` loop before it iterates through each element.
And `forEach` always returns `undefined`.

You can find the letter with `const missingLetter = alphabetSlice.find((e, i) => e !== array[i]);`

Answer (score 0):

`Array.forEach` does not return anything - like others already answered. `forEach` just performs a (lambda) function on all elements of an array.

You may want to inspect [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), as also noticed by others.

Here's a bit more generic solution (check missing from alfabet or some other given string):

```js
const findFirstMissing = (arr, from) => [...from
  .slice(from.indexOf(arr[0]), from.indexOf(arr[arr.length - 1]) + 1) ]
  .find((v, i) => v !== arr[i]) || `complete`;

let alfabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
console.log(findFirstMissing(["a", "b", "c", "d", "f"], alfabet));
console.log(findFirstMissing(["O", "Q", "R", "S"], alfabet));

let someRowOfCharacters = `Charlotte`;
console.log(findFirstMissing(`Charltte`.split(``), someRowOfCharacters));
console.log(findFirstMissing(`Charlotte`.split(``), someRowOfCharacters));
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers and comments already described, why it's not working and why you are getting an unexpected result. I just wanna show a different way to solve this.

You can make use of the fact, that the unicode chars are already sorted and increasing the code point of any value by one, will give you the following letter/char/number.

All you have to do is getting the code point from the lowest and the highest value in your array and test if any char inbetween is inside the array you are testing.

Using this method, you can test within any range, if a letter/char/emoji is missing in the passed list.

```js
function missingChars(arr) {
  if (Array.isArray(arr)) {
    // generate a sorted copy of the array passed as argument
    arr = arr.slice().sort();
    // length won't be 1 on emojis and so on, so just test for > 0
    if (!arr.every(val => (typeof val == 'string' || val instanceof String) && val.length)) {
        throw new Error("Every value must be a string with length > 0.");
    }
    // lowest item will be at pos 0 after sort()
    const first = arr[0].codePointAt(0),
      // highest item will be at the last position
      last = arr[arr.length-1].codePointAt(0),
      resultArr = [];
    // for every char in between the lowest and the highest
    for (let i = first; i < last;i++) {
      // create a string using his code point value
      const charToTest = String.fromCodePoint(i);
      // test if it is inside the array
      if (!arr.includes(charToTest)) {
        // if not, add it to  the result
        resultArr.push(charToTest);
      }
    }
    return resultArr;
  }
  return null;
}

console.log(missingChars(["", ""])); // ['', '', '', '", '', '']
console.log(missingChars(["e", "c", "a"])); // ['b', 'd']
console.log(missingChars(["0", "2"])); // ['1']
console.log(missingChars(["a", "b"])); // []

// ascii range
console.log(missingChars(['\u0000', '\u00FF'])); 

console.log(missingChars(['', 'a'])); // throws error
```